# Uninitialized constant Error while working with mongoid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rake-task

I have started working with mongoid gem but I am getting an Uninitialized constant error

I have defined a document Tweet

```
class Tweet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :tweet_id, type: Int  
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
  field :text, type: String         
  field :user_id, type: Int       

  embedded_in :user  
end
```

Another document User

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :screen_name, type: String
  field :user_id, type: Int

  embeds_many :tweets    
end
```

I want to write a rake task to create and insert tweets into database.
Code for the rake task

I have tweets stored in a file whose path is @pathtofile

```
task :readtweet => :environment do
    File.readlines(@pathtofile).each do |line|
        line=line.chomp()
        tweet_hash = JSON.parse(line)
        Tweet.new(created_at: my_hash['created_at'], text: my_hash['text'] )         
    end
end
```

But every time i execute the rake task it gives me error.

```
uninitialized constant Tweet::Int
/home/c0mrade/testapp/app/models/tweet.rb:4:in `<class:Tweet>'
/home/c0mrade/testapp/app/models/tweet.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/c0mrade/testsapp/lib/tasks/data.rake:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have followed the installation instructions on [mongodb site](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration)

Can anybody help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be `Integer` instead of `Int`? I don't know if this will fix your issue here but I didn't see `Int` in any of the docs (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! that was stupid of me to use Int there.